# SSIS variables in the query

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have ssis package which uses the SQLserver 2012 and 
have the variable : clientLastSync which holds datetime
and have the execute task
query as below

```
select * from clnt where opendt > convert(varchar, CAST (@[User::clientLastSync] as date),101)
```

If I execute the package, below error appears:

> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.   An OLE DB error has
>   occurred. Error code: 0x80040E07. An OLE DB record is available. 
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"   Hresult:
>   0x80040E07  Description: "Conversion failed when converting date
>   and/or time  from character string.".

Can you suggest what is wrong here. Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `opendt` and what is the value passed to the parameter `@[User::clientLastSync]`??

Comment: It seems you should leave CAST (@[User::clientLastSync] as date) without convert

Comment: if `@[User::clientLastSync]` is already datetime, why again `CAST` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass variables in SSIS as a `?`, and then define your variables in your parameter mapping pane.

I'm **assuming** that you aren't *silly* enough to be storing your dates as a `varchar`, thus your Direct input SQL in your Execute SQL Task becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM clnt WHERE opendt > ?;
```

Then, you need to go to your Parameter mapping pane and click Add. Select your variable's name (probably `User::clientLastSync` ) in the Variable name Column. Then Input as the direction. `DBTIMESTAMP` as your Data Type and ParameterName as 0 (if you had further parameters they would be 1, 2, 3, etc in the order they appear in your query). Leave Paramter Size as -1.

This should work as you intend now.

Comment: yes i agree, thanks. i do have some of the queries/tasks worked like as you suggested.   But my issue is, apologies forgot to mention in original post,that entire query is appended in the variable.  [User::query1] holds the query: SELECT * FROM clnt WHERE opendt >@[User::clientLastSync]  Dataaccess mode:SQL command from variable